# Setting the grid size in costmap

Tags: navigation, mapping, map-server, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Where can I set the cell size or grid size in costmap 2d? This is the size of the cells into which the map is divided. I am not sure whether this has to be done in costmap or map_server ? I can't find this in the documentation as well.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10717/setting-the-grid-size-in-costmap/) by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 365 on 2011-07-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See the [Map Management Parameters](http://www.ros.org/wiki/costmap_2d#Map_management_parameters) of the costmap_2d docs. Specifically, the `resolution` parameter is what you are looking for - it specifies the meters/cell for the costmap.

Note that that parameter (as well as the other size related parameters like width and height) only apply to rolling maps - if you are using a static_map, these parameters are pulled from the metadata of the static map. See the [OccupancyGrid](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html) message for details on the information that comes along with the static_map from the map_server.

---

Originally posted by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) with karma: 8406 on 2011-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1